# Using Flurry in iOS to track user's event, but I can only log the event defined in AppDelegate.m file.

Tags: ios, objective-c, flurry

I'm trying to make some logs using Flurry to track user's action. For example, I have 5 tabs in my main tabviewcontroller, when a user switch from one tab to another, I want to log the action. My code is like `[Flurry logEvent:@"user is visiting tab1"]`

in the viewDidLoad function. In the AppDelegate.m file, I add a similar line in the "application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions" function,

```
[Flurry logEvent:@"MyAPP just started."]
```

When I try to check the log event online, it only shows 1 event "MyApp just started". It seems that other events are not logged.

BTW, I start a session in the AppDelegate.m file, like

```
[Flurry startSession:@"my api key"];
[Flurry logEvent:@"MyApp just started"];
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for a stupid question - have you made sure (possibly with a breakpoint) that the line that should send the tab event is actually reached? Can you show whole `viewDidLoad` method?

Comment: Thanks @Losiowaty, no stupid questions. Yes, I'm sure the logEvent code is executed.`NSLog(@"Start to log event.");
    [Flurry logEvent: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"User %@ visit homepage.", user.userName]];
    NSLog(@"Done.");`

Comment: I move the code to the AppDelegate.m file, all the event can be logged. I think somehow the logEvent in other files are not "really executed".

Comment: Well, it should. Did you `#import` Flurry in other files where you used it?

Comment: Yes, I do import the header file into every file. I want to make sure that I only need to startSession once in the AppDelegate.m file, right? Then I can just use [Flurry logEvent] where I want to log any event. Is that right?